# How do we do a For-Each Assertion?

Tags: java, assert

Hi all I was wondering how do I put an entire block of code within an assertion?

For example, I have an array and I would like to do assertions on each value of the array. This is what my code looks like:

```
for (int value : values) {
    assert Within(value, x, y);
}
```

But of course if I run the program without `-ea` whereby the assertions are turned off, the loop still exists.

I was wondering how do I put the entire loop in an assertion statement?

**EDIT:**

argh dang Java is really too rigid at times, I ended up doing something functional like this:

```
assert Every(value, new F1<Boolean, Integer>() {
    Boolean Call(Integer value) {
        return Within(value, 0, 255);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a method

```
public boolean check(int... values) {
    for (int value : values) 
        if(!Within(value, x, y)) return false;
    return true;
}

assert check(values);
```

---

Another approach is to test for assertion if you have lots of checks

```
boolean assertEnabled = false;
assert assertEnabled = true;
if (assertEnabled) {
   // do lots of checks
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I've thought of this but isn't this too much boilerplate code for a simple assertion?

Comment: Its 6 lines instead or 3. It depends on how much you want to avoid the loop.

Comment: Well of course we had to avoid that loop if assertions are turned off!

Comment: it's not the amount of lines (since `for(int value:values) assert Within(value, x, y);`) is effectively *1 line*, but more of the conceptual bloat. for-each-assert isn't that rare.. So if my class has 5 methods that require this type of assertion wouldn't that mean I had to create 5 additional methods and name them check1, check2, check3, check4, check5 ?

Comment: could be check1 && check2 && check3 && check4 && check5 if you don't care which one failed.

Comment: I mean I have 5 different methods that requires foreach-assertion. So for each method `F` that require foreach-assertion I have to create a `check` method for `F`.

Comment: I have added another option which works for any amount of checks.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a method checking all the elements of the array :

```
assert allWithin(values, x, y);

...

private boolean allWithin(int[] values, int x, int y) {
    for (int value : values) {
        if (!within(value, x, y)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8, you have the option of using a Stream for this:

```
assert values.stream().allMatch(value -> within(value, x, y));
```

(If `values` is an array in your example, use `Arrays.stream(values)` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Extract the for loop into a boolean method and assert on its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really a problem? As far as I know Java compiler and JVM ignore waiting loops (empty loops). So, from my point of view it doesn't matter, if the whole block is asserted or not (the final binary should be the same (without any loop)).

---

**EDIT**:

This is how your test code should look like to ensure that HotSpot is used

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] values = new int[10000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        long a = System.nanoTime();
        for (int value : values);
        long b = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(b - a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is true. I measured and.. it proved me right (well at least on my machine it is). So the JVM doesn't ignore empty loops

Comment: I will try to lookup some article. Have you tried to repeat the code more than once. It is possible that the loops are elimited after "hotspot" recompilation...

Comment: Well there couldn't be any mistake. I've tested it a couple of times and the difference is huge. Test code: http://qweop.com/test/emptyloop . what are your results after testing it?

Comment: You have to run the testing code in the loop to ensure that hotspot is used. Repeated program run only causes the unoptimized bytecode to be generated every time you run the program. But if the tested code is in the loop, hotspot will after several iterations realize that part of the program is called repeatedly and thus should be optimized (the loop will be omited).